# Lightweight HTTP server for python desktop Application

Tags: python, webserver

I am currently working on a desktop application in which a pair of this application will have to communicate with each other using HTTP meaning that both will server as a client/server simultaneously. What python webserver will suffice for such desktop application?

Answer (score 4):

You haven't really given us much information, but depending on your use-case [SimpleHTTPServer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) might suffice. It's in the standard library, which is convenient.

There's also [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/), [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), [web.py](http://webpy.org/)...

Answer (score 1):

I have a sample HTTP server that you can find it here.

http://snipplr.com/view/57745/python-web-server/

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking at a bi-directional HTTP communication.

You can get many resources over it. HTML5 websocket, my favourite.

Check  [this resource](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-loreto-http-bidirectional-00) or BOSH.

Hope this helps.